# php form to pass dynamic value, an item ID to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I'm trying to pass a dynamic value, an ID of a product. Through a form so I can write in a mysql database.

My problem is that the value is not being passed on through the form. I suspect it's due to that I'm trying to pass a value from one table to another table. Should I set a temporary variable for this $item_id instead? Or is it possible to pass anyway? Please help..

My shopping cart, here I echoes out the $item_id, which shows the last $item_id visible on the browser:

```
<div>
<?php 
echo $item_id
?>
<form method="post" action="checkoutpage.php">
<input type="hidden" name="product_bought" value="<?php echo $item_id ?>">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

checkoutpage.php:

```
<?php 
session_start(); // Start session first thing in script
// Script Error Reporting
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
// Connect to the MySQL database  
include "storescripts/connect_to_mysql.php"; 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>checkout form</title>
</head>

<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
Name: <input type="text" name="name">
Email: <input type="text" name="email"><br />
Credit Card: <input type="text" name="credit_card">
<input type="hidden" name="product_bought" value='product_bought'>
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

insert.php

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","xxxx","xxxx","mystore");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO orders (name, email, credit_card, product_bought)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[credit_card]','$_POST[product_bought]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "1 record added";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You need to set the value on `checkoutpage.php` - at the moment, it's value is the plain string 'product_bought'. You can retrieve the value on that page in exactly the same way as you're retrieving it on `insert.php`

Comment: Won't fix your problem but you should add an `else` for your `echo "1 record added";` -- Plus add a semi-colon at the end of `echo $item_id` -- and is `session_start();` inside `connect_to_mysql.php` ?

Comment: Try this `$sql= ("INSERT INTO orders name, email, credit_card, product_bought 
VALUES 
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[credit_card]','$_POST[product_bought]'), $con)";`

Comment: Er - you don't need to have `$con` there, @Fred-ii- - that's just the line that's creating the query. You don't need to do anything with `$con` until the `mysqli_query()` call, and then it needs to be the first parameter.

Comment: @andrewsi Thanks Andrew. I thought that might have been "an" issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on checkout page you have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_bought" value='product_bought'>
```

and you should have:

```
<input type="hidden" name="product_bought" value='<?php echo $_POST['product_bought']; ?>'>
```

You are passing "product_bought" as the value.

I hope it fixes it.

Comment: Yep that fixes the problem! Originally I had: `<input type="hidden" name="product_bought" value='<?php echo $item_id ?>'>` but it didn't work and it just echoes the content of variable right to the database. So I almost gave up and just thought that a plain text or form name would make it haha. Thanks for helping me :)